# Parsing string to double - java

Tags: java, string, parsing, double, bank

For a project I have a program that is like a bank. The "bank" reads in a file with accounts in it that look like this: 
Miller
William
00001
891692 06    <----string that needs to be converted to double 
The last string has to be converted to a double so that the program can perform calculations on it like addition and subtraction, etc. 
And also I have to print it out in monetary format, i.e. $891692.06

I have this so far:

```
 public class Account {
      private String firstName, lastName;
      private int accountID;
      private String currentBalance; 

      private static int maxAccountID;

      public Account(String fN, String lN, int acct, String bal) {
         firstName = fN; lastName = lN;
         accountID = acct;
         currentBalance = bal;
         if(accountID > Account.maxAccountID)
            Account.maxAccountID = accountID;
      }     

  public double getBalance(){
        String [] s = currentBalance.split(" ");
        String balStr = "$"+s[0]+"."+s[1];
            double currentBalance = Double.parseDouble(balStr);
         return currentBalance;
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your question? In your code already you convert a String to a double with `Double.parseDouble(balStr)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your string representing `double` uses space `' '` instead of a decimal point, you can fix it by replacing the space with a dot, like this:

```
String currentBalanceStr = "891692 06";
double currentBalanceDbl = Double.parseDouble(currentBalanceStr.replaceAll(" ","."));
```

[Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/IYsn7d)

Comment: With this it's returning the amounts as '0.0'

Comment: @Gcap That is strange. Did you follow the link to see if your code does the same thing as mine?

Comment: Yes it looked at that.. the thing is that I have a string being inputted through currentBalanceStr from another class

Comment: @Gcap You should print `currentBalanceStr` to see its value before calling `parseDouble` then.

Comment: Nvmd its working lol but when the String is say "891692 60" it cuts off the 0 at the end, do you know of any way I can keep it?

Comment: @Gcap Use `DecimalFormat`. Take a look at [this link](http://ideone.com/6CsjWg) for a modified example. Don't forget to import `java.text.*` to use `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: will it still be kept as type double if I do that?

Comment: @Gcap The type in which you keep it is up to you. The last two lines of the example simply format the value with two characters at the end; they have nothing to do with storing it.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Double` for balance calculation is not a good idea, it makes more sense to use the `BigDecimal` because it is more precise.

You can also add the currency using the class bellow:

```
Locale enUSLocale =
    new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();

Currency currencyInstance = Currency.getInstance(enUSLocale);

System.out.println(
    "Symbol for US Dollar, en-US locale: " +
    currencyInstance.getSymbol(enUSLocale));
```

please go through [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html) for more details.

Comment: Not allowed to use BigDecimal in this project

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are doing some currency calculation, so always use BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal balStr = new BigDecimal(String.replaceAll(" ",".");
```

Comment: Good idea to use BigDecimal for precision calculations

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="891692 06";
Double.parseDouble(s.replace(" ", ".")); would do the trick
```

You can use [NumberFormatClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) from the API to get the monetary information.